# react-select doesn't play well in mobile when dropdown icon is "overridden" and onMenuOpen+onMenuClose are used

Tags: mobile, menu, overriding, dropdown, react-select

I am using react-select for value input in my web app. I have to override dropdown indicator icon according to design and some dynamic modifications has to be performed depending on the opened/closed status of the menu. I am using styled-components and I have simplified the code a bit to be presented here:

```
const DropdownIndicator = (props) => {
  return (
    <components.DropdownIndicator {...props}>
    </components.DropdownIndicator>
  );
};

<S.InputField
  disabled={disabled}
  labelLeft={labelLeft}
  noLabel={!label}
  className={className}
  fieldType={state?.type}
  inputType={state?.inputType}
  notClearable={notClearable}
  extendOnOpen={extendOnOpen && menuIsOpen}
  menuIsOpen={menuIsOpen}
  menuHeight={menuHeight}
>
  <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>

  <div className="input-wrapper">
    <Select
      id={id}
      placeholder={'test'}
      components={{ DropdownIndicator }}
      // menuIsOpen={menuIsOpen}
      onMenuOpen={() => {
        console.log('menu opened');
        setMenuIsOpen(() => true);
      }}
      onMenuClose={() => {
        console.log('menu closed');
        setTimeout(() => setMenuIsOpen(() => false), 3000);
      }}
    />
  </div>
</S.InputField>
```

Now, when I try to open the menu clicking on the Select's control field, the menu opens as expected, but when I want to open it clicking on the dropdown icon, the operation becomes hardly predictable - basically I get the 'menu opened' and 'menu closed' directly after, so menu doesn't stay open. Why could that be? Is it a bug in the react-select design?

The funny thing is, if I comment either `components={{ DropdownIndicator }}` or one of `onMenuOpen` or `onMenuClosed`, the menu opens/closes as expected, but never when both ("overridden" `DropdownIndicator` and `onMenuOpen`/`onMenuClosed`) are employed. And I put "overridden" in quotes as it is not technically overridden (I've removed the icon change from `<components.DropdownIndicator {...props}></components.DropdownIndicator>` as it doesn't impact the outcome), it's actually mimicking (as I understand) the default behaviour of react-select's menu flow.

Important! It only happens in mobile resolutions. Desktop res works just fine. So my understanding this has got something to do with onFocus/onBlur and the way they are treated in touch devices.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I cannot be 100% sure, but my colleague told me he found some workaround to this and it is related to moving the overridden part-component (meaning components.DropdownIndicator) outside of the actual component which renders the react-select component. In fact, what is happening is the menu is opened and it is closed right away (it just feels that the menu wasn't opened at all). Sorry I cannot test that right now, I'll post the results after trying that later.